# Cookies para busca inteligente em E-commerce

Tags: cookies, redirecionamento

Desejo fazer como por exemplo no site da Saraiva:

http://www.livrariasaraiva.com.br/

Ao fazer uma pesquisa (por ex: "Guia do Mochileiro das Galaxias") a url é direcionada para uma url de busca inteligente:

http://busca.livrariasaraiva.com.br/search#w=guia%20do%20mochileiro%20das%20galaxias&PAC_ID=&af=

São sites totalmente diferentes porém indênticos, e eles importam as informações de Nome, Carrinho, Produtos no Carrinho, Estado e qualquer informação relevante para compra de um site para o outro.

Minha dúvida é como fazem isso, eu andei pesquisando e vi sobre cookies, mas estou tendo algumas dificuldades de entender o conceito e de aplicar algum exemplo prático para ver como seria, será que existe alguma forma de me ajudar a entender melhor como funciona? Ou como monto algum cookie com os dados que preciso para transferência?

Comment: Na verdade você não precisa usar cookies, você quer realmente usa-los?

Comment: pesquise sobre como armazenar dados na sessão... pesquisa por localStorage e sessionStorage, provavelmente isso irá te dar alguma base.

Comment: Paulo, não necessariamente. Gostaria de saber como fazer, o que descobri foram os cookies até o momento...

Comment: Sobre o exemplo que você deu, não tem nada de "inteligente", é apenas um subdomínio, a sessão do usuário logado é passada como qualquer outra página ([com alguns ajustes](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=php%20session%20on%20subdomain)). E os dados da busca são passados por [GET](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=php%20get).

Comment: O que *provavelmente* ocorre é que a mesma aplicação é responsável pelos dois subdomínios (www e busca). As informações do usuário e carrinho podem estar sendo guardadas em variáveis de seção, e o cookie de seção na máquina do usuário devem valer para qualquer subdomínio. **Mas o que exatamente você está tentando fazer? Usar dois subdomínios, ou compartilhar informações entre dois sites totalmente distintos?**

Comment: O fato dos sites terem formatos diferentes não impede que eles usem a mesma base de dados. Basta você, ao enviar o usuário de um site para outro, colocar um único ID na URL ou mesmo num cookie. Note que bastaria penas o ID do carrinho do usuário, não precisando de nada mais para vincular as duas sessões, se a base com os ítens e dados do cliente for acessivel pelos dois endereços.

Answer (score 2):

Cookies não seriam necessários. Você pode montar a url com parâmetros via javascript, sendo que no evento `onLoad` da outra página você iria checar o valor do parâmetro e realizar a buscar utilizando ele.

Suponhamos que você tenha um `<input type=text id=busca>`, e um botão para buscar `<input type=button id=btnBuscar>` utilize o seguinte código:

```
$('#busca').onkeyup(function(){
  var ValorDigitado = $(this).val();
  var URLBusca      = "http://busca.livrariasaraiva.com.br/";
  var ParametrosURL = "search#w="+ValorDigitado+"&PAC_ID=&af=";
  $('#btnBuscar').click(function(){
    document.location.href = URLBusca+ParametrosURL;
  });
});
```

Então como resultado ao clicar você seria redirecionado para:

> http://busca.livrariasaraiva.com.br/search#w=Guia%20do%20Mochileiro%20das%20Galaxias&PAC_ID=&af=

Aí no caso, você mudaria essa URL para o seu endereço de busca, e dentro desta página de busca que teria de ser um `.php` ai você poderia resgatar o valor do parâmetro `w`:

```
$StringBusca = $_GET['w'];
```

Com a string de busca ficaria fácil, daí é só executar a busca em sua base de dados e retornar para o usuário.